# Why this regular expression in swift doesn't work?

Tags: swift, regex

#### Edited:

I am trying to replace words in string using regex in Swift 5.

my code:

```swift
    let text = "hi avoid avoid avoid"
    let regex = "/(avoid|another word|word3)/gi"
    let str = text.replacingOccurrences(of: regex, with: "", options: [.regularExpression])

    print(str) // will print: "hi avoid avoid avoid"
```

## expected result:

```
print(str) // will print: "hi "
```

So the regex should remove any avoid, another word or word3 words from the string

any help?

Comment: WHAT IS `getRegex()` here ?
Can you add the code regarding `getRegex()` ?

Comment: Does $1 mean the backreference to a group? I think the Problem is that there is noe second group. you only have one

Comment: How can the replacement string "$1@hoge.$2" mean you want to remove everything found by the regex, please clean up the posted code and clarify what you want help with.

Comment: sorry guys, I corrected the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let myString = "hi avoid avoid avoid"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(avoid|another word|word3)", 
                   options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, myString.count)
let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: myString, options: [], 
                  range: range, withTemplate: "")
print(modString)
```